# UltiSnips snippet to emulate `<Esc>`

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

Can someone please tell me how to write a snippet which can emulate/simulate the behaviour of pressing the `<Esc>` or `<Enter>` etc keys from keyboard?

The following doesn't work

```
snippet undo "just for argument's sake"
<esc>
endsnippet
```

neither does this

```
snippet undo "i want this to result in pressing the esc key"
`!p<esc>`
endsnippet
```

nor this

```
snippet undo "simulate esc behaviour"
`!p snip.rv=<esc>`
endsnippet
```

Comment: The real question here is why do you want to simulate `<ESC>`? Do you want to get out of insert mode? I feel like you'd be better off using mappings

Comment: @Zorzi Actually you can think that I am trying to create a snippet for undo etc commands. There should be a way to encode `<esc>` etc into snippets, right?

Comment: I don't think so, snippets are there to **insert**, so that's all they're good at. The can use functions (c.f. interpolation) to insert their return value, but I don't see why they would allow the encoding of <ESC>